# object display , without any dots

Tags: jquery

```
var total = {"S":1,"M":"","L":"","XL":"","XXL":""}//object

var totalsplit = JSON.stringify(total).split(',');
//try to spilt but wont work.

alert(totalsplit[0]);
```

my intention is do a check size count , and display the total on my html.

and now my total display on the html showing like this `{"S":1,"M":"","L":"","XL":"","XXL":""}`.

i was trying to use split but it did not work out, how do i going to remove all those dot and display like this

```
S:1  M:  L:  XL:  XXL:
```

thank.

Comment: `var totalsplit = JSON.stringify(total).split(',').join(' ').slice(1, -1).replace(/"/g, '');`

Comment: What exactly the output you want to achieve?

Comment: S:1  M:  L:  XL:  XXL

Comment: like this no more dots

Answer (score 2):

If `JSON.stringify()` isn't producing the output you need, it's better not to (ab)use it.

```
var totalSplit = Object.keys(total).map(function(k) {
    return k + ":" + total[k];
}).join("  ");
```

A slightly simpler version is possible with underscore.js, since this very useful library has a function specifically designed to map over objects:

```
var totalSplit = _.map(total, function(v, k) {
    return k + ':' + v;
}).join('  ');
```

Comment: I can assure you it works, unless you're using a _really_ old browser